# How can i get the original resolution of webview in cordova/phonegap?

Tags: cordova, webview, viewport, resolution

My test phone's resolution is 1920*1080, it used to be done well when i use phonegap online build(build.phonegap.com) or local phonegap version 3.1.0. But when I update the local Cordova to version 4.1.2, it work wrong.
  when i run js:alert( window.devicePixelRatio+";"+screen.width+";"+window.innerWidth),I get:3;360;360.
  So,if i define a 1px border,it looks like 3px!
I have tried some methods in a few days such as changing viewport settings or use plugin to change the webview'settings but it has no use.
  It really Stumped me. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Finally，I find the method:add “<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="17" />” to config.xml.
But I did'nt know why?If anybody can tell me about it?